# Automatic actions able during time in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

So, I wanted to create **Post** which can be subscribed by multiple users (Some kind of "looking for group to play with" site). And, after 4 hours passed, I want the author to be able to **Upvote** the participants, and after 24 Hours passed, the post should be automatically deleted from the database.
To make it, i've added a constructor to my **Post.cs**

```
       public Post()
    {
        Subscribers = new List<ApplicationUser>(); //This part is not important
      int  timeToRateInt = Convert.ToInt32(AddedOn.Hour) + 4;
        int timeToDeleteInt = Convert.ToInt32(AddedOn.Hour) + 24;
        int now = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Hour);
        if(now>=timeToRateInt)
        {
            CanRate = true;
        }
        if(now>=timeToDeleteInt)
        {
            ToDelete = true;
        }

    }
```

The **CanRate** and **ToDelete** Are properties which i use later, but that is not that important, because program does not work properly at this point. (Later everything works perfectly fine if I manually change the database table data). So, **CanRate** and **ToDelete** Are still set to **false**. What is the issue? And if it should be assigned through controller, how to make sure it will change after user refreshes the site(Any page)?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so thing I've done is cutting the code and pasting it into my **Action** in Controller responsible for partial view. So this way everything works perfectly fine. I'll keep this question and answer here if anyone will have this issue.